Сочетание поставленных с разной целью тире и запятых
Как правильно сочетать тире и запятые? Допустим, я, например, хочу использовать в тексте такую конструкцию: "[Первый однородный член] — [Вставная конструкция, обрамлённая тире] — [Второй однородный член]..." — где в такой ситуации будет правильно поставить запятую? После первого однородного члена? В конце вставной конструкции? После тире? Не ставить вообще?
И будет ли это работать аналогично в других синтаксических конструкциях?

Не этот вопрос нет и не будет объективного ответа, пока вы не оформите вопрос в виде конкретного предложения. На постановку запятой до или после вставной конструкцией повлияет то, к какому из однородных членов она имеет отношение. Кроме того, не исключены ситуации, где внутри самих однородных членов окажутся свои запятые, поставленные по иным основаниям. С большой долей уверенности можно утверждать лишь то, что запятая из-за появления тире никуда не исчезнет. На форуме немало вопросов с такой пунктуацией, если вы нуждаетесь в примерах.
В общем виде можно дать такой ответ по вашей схеме:
[Первый однородный член] — [Вставная конструкция, обрамлённая тире, имеющая отношение к первому однородному члену], — [Второй однородный член]
[Первый однородный член], — [Вставная конструкция, обрамлённая тире, имеющая отношение ко второму однородному члену] — [Второй однородный член]
